# add and remove last bit

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to determine the next and previous even number with bitwise operations.

So for example for the next function:

```
x    nextEven(x)
1       2
2       2
3       4
4       4
```

and for the previous:

```
x    previousEven(x)
1       0
2       2
3       2
4       4
```

I had the idea for the `nextEven` function something like: `value = ((value+1)>>1)<<1;`

And for the `previousEven` function something like: `value = ((value)>>1)<<1`

is there a better approach?, without comparing and seeing if the values are even or odd.

Thank you.

Comment: The better approach _is_ comparing values to see if they're even or odd. Tricks like this may look clever but they rarely are. Optimise for readability first. Only move on to performance optimisation when you've identified a specific bottleneck. I'll guarantee the difference between compare/set and multi-bit-ops is not worth the inherently unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing a right shift followed by a left shift to clear the LSB isn't very efficient.

I'd use something like:

```
previous: value &= ~1;
next: value = (value +1) & ~1;
```

The `~1` can (and normally will) be pre-computed at compile time, so the `previous` will end up as a single bit-wise operation at run-time. the `next` will probably end up as two operations (increment, `and`), but should still be quite fast.

About the best you can hope for from the shifts is that the compiler will recognize that you're just clearly the LSB, and optimize it to about what you'd expect this to produce anyway.

Comment: I do not think "previous: value &= ~1;" works.  If "value" had the original value of 2, performing "previous: value &= ~1;" would have it remain at 2, rather than the desired value of 0.  Recommend instead "previous: value = (value - 1) & ~1;"

Comment: @chux: According to the table in the question, for an input of 2, the desired "previous even" result is 2.

Answer (score 3):

you could do something like this

for previous even

```
unsigned prevev(unsigned x)
{
    return x-(x%2);//bitwise counterpart x-(x&1);
}
```

for next even

```
unsigned nxtev(unsigned x)
{
    return (x%2)+x; //bitwise counterpart x+(x&1);
}
```

Comment: @downvoter why the downvote?atleast leave a comment when you are downvoting

Answer (score 1):

Say you're using `unsigned int`s, previous even (matching your values - we could argue about whether previous even of 2 should be 0 etc) is simply `x & ~1u`.  Next even is previous even of x + 1.

Answer (score 1):

Tricks like Duff's Device, or swapping two variables with XOR, or working out next and previous even number with bitwise operations *seem* clever, but they rarely are.

The best thing you can do as a developer is to optimise for readability first and only tackle performance once you've identified a *specific* bottleneck that is causing *real* problems.

The best code for getting the previous even number (by your definition where the previous even number of 2 is 2) is simply writing something like:

```
if ((num % 2) == 1) num--; // num++ for next.
```

or (slightly more advanced):

```
num -= num % 2;            // += for next.
```

and letting the insane optimising compilers figure out the best underlying code.

Unless you need to do these operations billions of times per second, readability should always be your prime concern.

Comment: I agree with your developer philosophy, but the questioner did ask how to do it with bitwise operations.  So a bit-wise solution better answers the query.  (Although I think it would be _very_ challenging to create a bit-wise only solution.)

Comment: @harold, you find it harder to see that subtracting one from an odd number gives you the next lowest even number? And yet you have no troubles with a shift-right/shift-left? Perhaps you've been working at too low a level for too long :-)

Comment: Oh no, that part was simple - but it took a second before I realized that's what it's doing. The shifts were immediately obvious to me - drop the lsb. But yes, I've been doing assembly for the past 8 years and I'm beyond saving now :)

Answer (score 1):

**Previous even number:**
For previous even number I prefer **Jerry Coffin**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706038/2106973)

```
// Get previous even number
unsigned prevEven(unsigned no)
{
    return (no & ~1);
}
```

---

**Next even number:**
I try to use only bitwise operator's but still i use one unary minus(-) operator to get next number.

```
// Get next even number
unsigned nextEven(unsigned no)
{
    return (no & 1) ? (-(~no)) : no ;
}
```

**Working of Method nextEven():**

- If number is even return the same number,
  if no is even it's LSB is `0` otherwise `1`
  Get LSB of number => `number & 1`
- If number is odd return the number + 1,
  Add 1 to number => `-(~number)`

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int previous(unsigned int x)
{
    return x & 0xfffffffe;
}

unsigned int next(unsigned int x)
{
   return previous(x + 2);
}
```

Comment: you are assuming unsigned int is 32 bits. instead use `~1` for that magic number you'l be safe:)